# How to view execution logs for a published GSheet Editor Add On?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Our GSheet Add-on is published in Google Marketplace and users are using it after installing. There are some issues reported and we want to check logs (created by console.log in apps-script).
During development, we navigate to appscript editor and click on "Executions" to see logs.
How can we see these logs of another user who has installed our add-on?

I tried installing our addon with a new gmail id and looked for appscript logs in https://console.cloud.google.com. Could not find anything.